# How to call a non-static method through namespace

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I don't fully understand GameScene::onTime. onTime isn't a static method.

1.Does  GameScene::onTime return a function pointer?

2.Is it possible to write this->onTime(1.0f); ?

```
void GameScene::createGameInterface() {
   this->schedule(schedule_selector(GameScene::onTime), 1.0f);
}

void GameScene::onTime(float dt)
{
  if (isPaused)
        return;
  sec++;
  timer_lbl->setString(Utils::secondsToTimeString((int)sec));
}
```

Where

```
typedef void (Ref::*SEL_SCHEDULE)(float);
#define CC_SCHEDULE_SELECTOR(_SELECTOR) static_cast<cocos2d::SEL_SCHEDULE>(&_SELECTOR)

void Node::schedule(SEL_SCHEDULE selector)
{
  this->schedule(selector, 0.0f, CC_REPEAT_FOREVER, 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: What is `schedule`? What is `schedule_selector`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the names, the code is scheduling a function call on some timer.

1. `GameScene::onTime` is a member function pointer, though to be fully correct in C++, it should be spelled `&GameScene::onTime` (i.e. explicitly include the address taking operator).
2. `this->onTime(1.0f)` would change the meaning of the code as it would call `onTime` synchronously instead of scheduling the call asynchronously, at a later time.

Comment: Emphasis on *member function pointer*. This is the thing you can search for.